# Upgrading project to Qt5 throws error

Tags: qt, qt5

I upgraded my Qt project from Qt4 to Qt5. Now whenever I try to include a widget say QLabel or QLineEdit, the compiler throws an error. The project is quite huge so I tried running a sample Hello World GUI program in Qt5 and it worked, thus the installation can't be at fault. I will paste the error below. And if more code is needed please let me know.

[image: Error in QtCreator while Building the Project]

The .pro file:
[image: .pro file]

Comment: At first glance, m7globals.h seems to declare QPair<QVariant, QVariant> as a metatype in line 225, while Qt5.9.3 already has this declaration in qmetatype.h, line 2078. If so, just wrap the declaration in m7globals.h into #if QT_VERSION < 0x050000 ... #endif

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that was actually for screenshots of the error. Should I copy paste the error message instead? It seemed to be in a more readable format this way.

Comment: @VasundharaMehta Screenshots are not desired (if possible), because they are not searchable and depend on external resources which may not be available in the future.

Comment: Constructing a [mcve] may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libqxt extension for qt4 doesn't work properly with qt5, so that was the error. Thanks for all the help guys. cheers